# How to input a string one charecter at a time into a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So i have a string and i need to put it into a 2d array this is what i have so far.

```
mazeString = ".............."    
char[][] mazeArray = new char [50][30];
         for (int i = 0; i < (height*2)-1; i++){
           for (int j = 0; j < (width*2)-1; j++){
              mazeArray[j][i] = mazeString.next();
           }

         }
```

Comment: Why are you calling Scanner mazeString when it was already initialized?

Comment: maze*String* is a *String*, not a `Scanner`. This won't compile.

Comment: Im new to java.  I thought puting the string in the scanner would lets me do different things like .next()

Comment: Why do you want to put the string into a 2-dimensional array? A string is a 1-dimensional array of characters. How do you discriminate between the 2 dimensions?

Comment: Hi there @user3267256. Can you explain maybe what you are trying to do? You say you need to put the string into the 2D array, but how do you want to do that? Can you show a sample string and an example of which strings in the String[] (I assume you will split the String) you want to put in an example of the 2D array. Just show us a simple example, and maybe we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in the comments, `mazeString` is declared and initialized as a String Literal. All `.next()` methods are reserved for Scanner objects. Java doesn't let you use scan

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out.

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
      mazefile = mazefile + input.nextLine();
    }


for (int i = 0; i < (height*2)+1; i++){
       for (int j = 0; j < (width*2)+1; j++){
          mazeArray[i][j] = mazefile.charAt(counter);
          counter++;
       }
     }
```